# How to get the angle between the horizon line and the device in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, device-orientation

I want to show a cup of water in my web page.I want when the user rotate their device, the water should go down to the  horizon line as natural.

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', this.handleOrientation.bind(this));

handleOrientation(orientData) {
    var absolute = orientData.absolute;
    var alpha = orientData.alpha;
    var beta = orientData.beta;
    var gamma = orientData.gamma;
}
```

From the api above , I can get those four angle information. But I don't know how to get the current angle from the device to the horizon line so that I could set my water to rotate to the horizon line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [the example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) from MDN and a bit of [trigonometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994194/how-to-convert-x-y-coordinates-to-an-angle) I was able to come up with the code below. I successfully tested this on Chrome on Android, Firefox sadly wouldn't fire the `deviceorientation` event (even the example on MDN didn't work).

The other caveat is *screen* orientation, i.e. if your device is currently in landscape mode. Old APIs (`window.orientation`) are unsupported in some browsers, new APIs (`screen.orientation`) haven't been fully implemented and behave differently.

```js
var watercup = document.querySelector('#watercup');

function handleOrientation(event) {
  var x = event.beta;  // In degree in the range [-180,180], x, 'front to back'
  var y = event.gamma; // In degree in the range [-90,90], y, 'left to right'
  var z = event.alpha; // 0-360, z, compass orientation

  // coord 1: 0,0
  // coord 2: x,y
  // calculate the angle
  var rad = Math.atan2(y, x);
  var deg = rad * (180 / Math.PI);

  // take into account if phone is held sideways / in landscape mode
  var screenOrientation = screen.orientation || screen.mozOrientation || screen.msOrientation;
  // 90, -90, or 0
  var angle = screenOrientation.angle || window.orientation || 0; 
  
  deg = deg + angle; 

  watercup.innerHTML = Math.round(deg);
  watercup.style.transform = 'rotate('+ -deg +'deg)';
}

window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handleOrientation);
```

```css
#watercup {
  border:2px solid #aaa;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 20%, lightblue 20%, blue);
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="watercup"></div>
```

Comment: Whenver I rotate my S7 counter-clockwise, the calculated degrees angle jumps from 60 to 35, the same failure occurs clockwise, skipping from -60 to -35. Any ideas why this happens? I have a **Protractor app** that measures all 360 angles perfectly fine, so the sensors are not the problem. Thanks for the detailed reply anyway, it almost worked perfectly!

Comment: Is there any chance someone could explain (leaving aside screen orientation angle) why `atan2(gamma, beta)` yields the needed angle? BTW I'm not totally rusty with trigonometrics. `atan2(y, x)` works with (x, y) coordinates of a point. How can beta and gamma angles be interpreted as coordinates? And then why that combination gives the needed angle? For references, I'm aware of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_orientation_events/Orientation_and_motion_data_explained) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Eulerangles.svg). Thanks