# How to calculate angle of rectangle using corner position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, angle, rectangles

I have a rectangle like this...

[image: image 1]

... and I also know the rectangle's corner positions, as in the array below:

```
var corners = [[107, 0], [0, 21], [111, 24], [4, 45]]
```

---

Because I need to calculate the rectangle's angle like I've symbolized in the image above, my idea was to just use this code:

```
var rectangle_angle = ((180/Math.PI) * Math.atan((a[1] - b[1]) / (a[0] - b[0]))).toFixed(2)
console.log('angle : ' + rectangle_angle)
```

In the case above I'm using the first two corner points to calculate the angle:

```
var a = corners[0], b = corners[1]
```

---

But e.g. I was using a rectangle like below and tried to calculate the rectangle's angle...

[image: image2]

(corners: `[[101, 0], [110, 22], [0, 38], [9, 60]]`)

... but the result I got is this -> `angle : 67.75`, what absolutely is not the right rotation angle.

Afterwards I fixed the problem by just using `corner[0]` and `corner[2]` for the calculation instead of using `corner[0]`  and `corner[1]`.

So the result I get now is `-20.62°`. Way better.

---

Now my question: **How can I extract the right points from my corners array that I have to use for my calculation?**

You can try the function here:

```js
var corners = [[107, 0], [0, 21], [111, 24], [4, 45]]

var a = corners[0], b = corners[1]
var rectangle_angle = ((180/Math.PI) * Math.atan((a[1] - b[1]) / (a[0] - b[0]))).toFixed(2)
console.log('angle : ' + rectangle_angle)
```

Comment: Bro, please read the question, I am not trying to find the corners, I'm trying to calculate the angle of a rectangle @JonasW.

Comment: `Now my question: How can I extract the right corner positions that I have to use for my calculation?` but the problem is finding the right corners.

Comment: `...and I also know the rectangles corner positions...` trying to find the angle, yes!

Comment: Do you always put the X axis in the opposite direction? Confusing.

Comment: Do you mean the Y asis in my images? - Well yeah.. because I can not really get your comment :( @trincot

Comment: No, I mean your X axis, which seems to run from right to left. Normally, you would have them: `|_`, but you have `_|`

Comment: Well, your right. Yeah customary thing! However, I hope it will not affect my question :p

Comment: This has been fun and all, but: duplicate of [How to convert x,y coordinates to an angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994194/how-to-convert-x-y-coordinates-to-an-angle)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I extract the right points from my corners array that I have to use for my calculation?

Your a corner of your calculation is where your x-value is 0. Therefor you need to search for the `x = 0` value:

```
var a;
$.each(corners, function(i, corner) {
    if (corner[0] === 0) {
        // you have found your a corner (corners[i])
        a = corner;
    }
});
```

Your b corner of your calculation is where your y value is 0:

```
var b;
$.each(corners, function(i, corner) {
    if (corner[1] === 0) {
        // you have found your b corner (corners[i])
        b = corner;
    }
});
```

But then your calculation needs to be fixed as following:

```
var rectangle_angle = ((180/Math.PI) * Math.atan((a[1] - b[1]) / (b[0] - a[0]))).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Also not working with a clockwise rotated rectangle - `[[10, 0], [0, 1], [108, 27], [82, 27]]`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the unexpected angle is that your two rectangles have their corners defined in a different order.

The first one has as first two corners the two end-points of its lower **long** side, while the second one has as first two corners the two end-points of a **short** side of it. As can be seen from the image, that shorter side indeed has a steeper angle.

As you indicate you cannot influence the order of the points in the rectangle's definitions, you could proceed as follows:

- sort the corners by increasing Y coordinate: the first corner will then be the bottom one, and the next two will be points with which that bottom corner has an edge
- Of these two edges, choose the longest one
- Perform the calculation of the angle based on that edge

Here is some code you could use to make that happen:

```js
function rectangleTilt(rect) {
    const distance2 = (a, b) => (a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2,
        angle = (a, b) => 180 - Math.atan2(b[1]-a[1], b[0]-a[0]) * 180 / Math.PI,
        // Sort the corners by increasing Y coordinate:
        [a, b, c] = rect.slice().sort( (a, b) => a[1] - b[1] );
    // Return the angle of the longest edge having the lowest corner:
    return distance2(a, b) < distance2(a, c) ? angle(a, c) : angle(a, b);
}

function drawRectangle(ctx, rect) {
    const [a, b, c, d] = rect.slice().sort( (a, b) => a[1] - b[1] );
    ctx.moveTo(a[0], a[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(b[0], b[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(d[0], d[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(c[0], c[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(a[0], a[1]);
    ctx.stroke(); 
}

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// Make Y axis go upwards, and X axis backwards
ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var rect = [[101, 0], [110, 22], [0, 38], [9, 60]];
drawRectangle(ctx, rect);
console.log(rectangleTilt(rect).toFixed(2) + "°");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: I'm completely aware that my rectangles have different corner characteristics, but I can not define my rectangle because I got this rectangle corner points, I've mentioned above and I'd like to now which of them I have to use in my calculation!

Comment: I added an algorithm (and snippet) for finding the longest edge linked to the bottom corner, and performing the angle calculation on that.

Answer (score 0):

Filter through `corners` so you can get corners a and b:

```js
const corners = [[107, 0], [0, 21], [111, 24], [4, 45]]

const cornerA = corners.filter(x => x[1] == 0).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))
const cornerB = corners.filter(y => y[0] == 0).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))

const rectangleAngle = ((180/Math.PI) * Math.atan((cornerA[1] - cornerB[1]) / (cornerA[0] - cornerB[0]))).toFixed(2)

console.log(rectangleAngle)
```

Comment: Hey John, look like a good working solution but I got problems with this corner positions `[[10, 0], [0, 1], [108, 27], [82, 27]]`. (In this case the rectangle is rotated clockwise!)

Comment: you might probably want to swap cornerA and cornerB